# JMeter: How to find the reason of a java.net.SocketTimeoutException?

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, load-testing, socket-timeout-exception

I am making load test for my web application, and I set the connect timeout and response timeout to be 20 seconds, and sometimes I am getting exceptions like:

> Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Non HTTP response message: Read timed out

I get the above exception in JMeter test result, and there are no errors thrown in my application, and no stacktrace available to trace the exception.

I want to discover the cause of the message: is the app waiting for something to process, or slow SQL, or hung thread, or application is refusing connections because maxed out?

How can I find why this exception is thrown, and how can I fix it?

Comment: @Raedwald, in JMeter test results there are no stack trace available to track down the application, and also my application don't throw exception to trace either, so please take the close vote.

Comment: @Raedwald if you have experience with JMeter you will know what i am talking about, please don't underestimate me that much, this answer is humiliating to my experience :( :(

Comment: Is it happening with 1 thread? If it happens when you increase users - it could be your application issue. if not, Do you have enough heap set for JMeter?

Comment: What's the mystery? There is only one reason. The read timed out. The server didn't send anything  within the timeout period.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you improve debugging activities (in jMeter) in the following way:

- try to add debug postprocessor to your http sampler

[image: debugPostProcessor]

- launch log viewer (jMeter log viewer before any http
  sampler(-s)/script(-s)   execution

[image: log viewer]

probably this could help you to figure  out why you're facing socket timeout.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: i am using blazemeter to run my test scripts, any ideas how to debug ?

Comment: What about idea to export your blazemeter script in jMeter  using this button: http://gyazo.com/249f1a3de843aef963981ae068327385  , and try to perform your script in jMeter taking into consideration what I've mentioned you above ?

Comment: btw, I notice that response looks like "Non HTTP response code:" . Are you sure that you use proper endpoints (webApi endpoint) of your  application to perform HTTP requests ?